# Glusterfs-server can't stop in good status

Tags: centos7, systemd, glusterfs

Glusterfs-server can't stop in good status.

I have been trying the following steps to install glusterfs and start service.

```
yum install centos-release-gluster
yum install glusterfs-server
systemctl start glusterd
```

and stop it.

```
systemctl stop glusterd
```

Then displayed following status "Active: failed".

```
glusterd.service - GlusterFS, a clustered file-system server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/glusterd.service; disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since 火 2017-01-24 18:23:55 JST; 4s ago
  Process: 2523 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/glusterd -p /var/run/glusterd.pid --log-level $LOG_LEVEL $GLUSTERD_OPTIONS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2524 (code=exited, status=15)

 1月 24 18:23:52 ds009 systemd[1]: Started GlusterFS, a clustered file-system server.
 1月 24 18:23:55 ds009 systemd[1]: Stopping GlusterFS, a clustered file-system server...
 1月 24 18:23:55 ds009 systemd[1]: glusterd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=15/n/a
 1月 24 18:23:55 ds009 systemd[1]: Stopped GlusterFS, a clustered file-system server.
 1月 24 18:23:55 ds009 systemd[1]: Unit glusterd.service entered failed state.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Using environment is"CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)"

And installed glusterfs-server version is 3.8.8-1.el7.

Does anyone have an idea what wrong is and to fix this.

Comment: I think this issue from RedHat might be related: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1384762

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround.

Edit /usr/lib/systemd/system/glusterd.service file as following.

```
[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/run/glusterd.pid
LimitNOFILE=65536
Environment="LOG_LEVEL=INFO"
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/glusterd
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/glusterd -p /var/run/glusterd.pid  --log-level $LOG_LEVEL $GLUSTERD_OPTIONS
ExecStopPost=/usr/bin/systemctl reset-failed glusterd  # Add this
KillMode=process
```

The failed status is clear when the GlusterFS service stop.